# TestNgAnt task not honoring command line option -groups

Tags: java, testng

I have master suite file which intern call multiple features test suites. 
ex:

0)

```
<suite name="MasterTest">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="./suite1.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="./suite2.xml"/>    
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

1)

```
<suite name="featureTest.feature1">
    <test name="featureTest.feature1">
        <classes>
             <class name="featureTest.feature1.Testcase1"/>
             <class name="featureTest.feature1.Testcase2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

2)

```
 <suite name="featureTest.feature1">
    <test name="featureTest.feature1">
        <classes>
             <class name="featureTest.feature2.Testcase1"/>
             <class name="featureTest.feature2.Testcase2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Each test cases is tagged with different priorities
ex:

```
@Test(description = "testcase1", groups={ "P0" })
@Test(description = "testcase2", groups={ "P1" })
```

Now If I execute master test suite with -Groups="P0"  then P0 test cases are not executing from command line instead all test cases are executing.

where I am missing ?